# Can we convert react-select styles to styled-components

Tags: css, node.js, typescript, styled-components, react-select

Is there any way to convert the following styles (**react-select**) to the **styled-components**?

```
export const styles: StylesConfig<options, IsMulti> = {

    valueContainer: (provided, state) => ({
        ...provided,
        height: "30px",
    }),

    option: (provided, state) => ({
        ...provided,
        '&:hover': { backgroundColor: "#F7F7F7" },
        color: "#F7F7F7",
    }),

    control: (provided, state) => {
        return {
            ...provided,
            fontWeight: 100,
            '&:hover': { 
                background: `linear-gradient(#F7F7F7, #F7F7F7), linear-gradient(75deg, #FD6453 50%, #FCD889 50%) border-box;`,
            },
        };
    }
};
```

I used the below code

```
import Select from "react-select";
---------------
---------------
---------------
<Select
   options={options}
   getOptionLabel={getOptionLabel}
   getOptionValue={getOptionValue}
   onChange={onChange}
   styles={styles}
/>
```

Or is any alternative solution for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in github - https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/4230